# Create dynamic route using list of string as paths in React JS with BrowserRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx, url-routing

Below is the current implementation of my router which is kind of hard-coded and redundant.
I have an object which contains all the path for example like below

path = ["physical-health","general-health","wellbeing"];

I want to make it dynamic to reduce the hard coding and make it more scalable.
Something like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < path.length-1; i++) {
        <Route exact path={this.state.basePath + path[i]} render={() => <Welcome />} />
    }
```

But its doesn't seem to be working inside BrowserRouter.

```
render() {
        return(
            <BrowserRouter history={history}>
                <div className="">
                    <div id="maincontent">
                        <Route exact path={this.state.basePath +"/physical-health"} render={() => <Welcome />} />
                        <Route exact path={this.state.basePath +"/general-health"} render={() => <Welcome />} />
                        <Route exact path={this.state.basePath +"/wellbeing"} render={() => <Welcome />} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .map() to do what you're looking for:

```
path = ["/physical-health","/general-health","/wellbeing"];
path.map(p => <Route exact path={this.state.basePath + p} render={() => <Welcome />} />)
```

Another way:

```
path = ["physical-health","general-health","wellbeing"];
path.map(p => <Route exact path={`${this.state.basePath}/${p}`} render={() => <Welcome />} />)
```

For a full example:

```
render() 
{
    const path = ["physical-health","general-health","wellbeing"];
    return(
        <BrowserRouter history={history}>
            <div className="">
                <div id="maincontent">
                    {path.map(p => <Route exact path={`${this.state.basePath}/${p}`} render={() => <Welcome />} />)}
                </div>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @wrxsti I implemented you solution and that is what I wanted. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: @jitendrarautela No problem!